# how to stop audio recorder at desired time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mediarecorder

///my HTML

```
<button onclick="startRecording()" > Record </button>
<button onclick="stopRecording()" > Stop </button>
```

//and here is my js functions

```
function startRecording(){
  console.log("stop button clicked");
   .......
   .......
   rec.record();
   .......
   .......

   setTimeout( function(){ 
            console.log("10 seconds timeout");
            stopRecording();
          }  , 10000 );
}

function stopRecording(){
   console.log("start button clicked");
   .......
   .......
   rec.stop();
   .......
   .......
}
```

the user can start and stop recording but i want that if user doesn't click the stop button then the stopRecording function should be called at given time which stop the recorder.I used setTimeout in to first function to achieve this which works well if user doesn't click the stop button,

The issue is, if user click the stop button before given time then stopRecording func run but after that given time the setTimeout again call the stopRecording function.

i want that if user click the stop button then setTimeout should not work. please help me to fix this and also, is it possible to get how much time the start recording works for, i mean the time of audio file in sec. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the timeout inside the stopRecording function, something like this:

```
var timeout_status = 0;

function startRecording(){
  console.log("stop button clicked");
   .......
   .......
   rec.record();
   .......
   .......

   timeout_status  = setTimeout( function(){ 
            console.log("10 seconds timeout");
            stopRecording();
          }  , 10000 );
}

function stopRecording(){
   console.log("start button clicked");
    window.clearTimeout(timeout_status);
   .......
   .......
   rec.stop();
   .......
   .......
}
```